# PHP preg_replace remove text from substring and end tag?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this string (html) and want to remove all from " .cf " to end of paragraph.

```
$html = <p>text to keep .cf text to remove </p>
```

So, all between .cf. (including .cf) and </p> should be removed to have:

```
$html = <p>text to keep</p>
```

I try several ways but can not find solution ( think i am mixing spaces and the point )

```
$html = preg_replace('/ \.cf (.*?)<\/p>/i','</p>',$html);

$html = preg_replace('#{{ \.cf (.*?)</p>}}#s','</p>',$html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$html = '<p>text to keep .cf text to remove </p>';
$html = preg_replace('/\s+\.cf\s*(.*?)<\/p>/i','</p>',$html);
var_dump($html);
```

`\s` represents **white space char**.

`+` represents **one or more**.

`*` represents **zero or more**.

Just to be more clear.

`\s+\.cf\s*` means that there will be `one or more white space char before .cf and zero or more white space char after .cf`

Comment: Oh, the \s (white space char) was something I was not aware (not a "real" coder"). Will try now, many thanks!!